# Python - Have a changing ASCII image above a user input

Tags: python

I would like to have a user input at the bottom of my terminal window, with an ASCII image above it. The image is going to be constantly changing, but I cannot figure out how to do this without somehow canceling the raw_input() function (the function I am going to use for the user input). If I could cancel it, the data that the user already answered would get removed, too. Is there any way I can do this, and how?

Using python 2.7.

Comment: This is why they invented GUIs.

Comment: Yes put you can build TUI. It's funny.

Comment: If you love coding with python then for this problem the next step would wxPython. http://wxpython.org/

Comment: Maybe look into the `curses` API.

Answer (score 2):

You really want to use:

- A GUI. Python ships with [tkinter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html), but there are many other options, such as GTK, QT, & many more.
- [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#module-curses), this will abstract a lot of the low-level terminal stuff for you. This will only work on UNIX systems (ie. not Windows).

For the sake of explaining *why* you want to use either of these options, here's a very simple example which, *more or less*, does what you want:

```
import time, thread, sys

s = [
 'Hello, world',
 "It's a bloody aardvark!",
 'Are you suggesting coconuts migrate?',
 "Don't mention the war!",
]

def change(a):
    n = 0

    while True:
        print '\x1b7',       # Save cursor position
        print '\x1b[1A',     # Move cursor up
        print '\x1b[2K',     # Clear line
        print '\r',          # Go to position 1 one the line
        print s[n]           # Print string

        n = (n + 1) % len(s)

        print '\x1b8',       # Resore cusor position

        sys.stdout.flush()   # Make sure we print everything
        time.sleep(2)

print ''
thread.start_new_thread(change, ('',))

i = raw_input('> ')
print '\rYour input: %s' % i
```

We "need" to use a thread, because `raw_input` is blocking; you can also get the contents of the screen, but I'm not 100% sure how (this is just an example).
I hope it's obvious you do *not* want to build a larger application like this. `curses` abstracts all this away from you quite nicely.